# the dimension problem of complex projection

Tags: geometry, complex-geometry, projective-space, dimension-theory-analysis

Is it true that $\operatorname{dim }H^{0}(P^{n},P(T^{*}P^{n}))>0$? That is, is there a global holomorphic section? Here $P^{n}$ is $n$-dimensional complex projection space and $P(T^{*}P^{n})=T^{*}P^{n}/\mathcal{C}^{*}$.

Comment: Please try to make a little clearer what your question is. Are you asking whether the given inequality is true? Or are you asking to prove it is true?

Comment: I donot know the inequality is true.i want to know the inequality whether true or not ？ thanks

Answer (score 0):

since
$$H^{q}(\mathbb{P}^{N},\Omega^{p})=0 \quad if\quad  p\neq q$$ where $\Omega^{p}$ is holomorphic $p$-form.thus
$$H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{N},T^{*}\mathbb{P}^{N})=H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{N},\Omega^{1})=0$$
then $H^{0}(\mathbb{P}^{N},P(T^{*}\mathbb{P}^{N}))=0$